# Can I take a DISTINCT set of a COALESCE'd set of data?

Tags: sql, distinct, coalesce, distinct-values

I have the following bit of code, and it works so far:

```
SELECT  
    [id],
    COALESCE ([Company], [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName]) as Customer
FROM [some_database].[dbo].[some_table]
ORDER BY Customer
```

However, I'd like to use the DISTINCT keyword to eliminate duplicate "Customer" entries.  Is this possible?  I've tried it a few different ways, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have multiple customer entries with the same name, you have to pick one ID for a given name. Here's an example of picking the most recently created (ie `max()`), but you may want the first created (ie `min()`):

```
SELECT  
    Max([id]) as id,
    COALESCE ([Company], [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName]) as Customer
FROM [some_database].[dbo].[some_table]
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY Customer
```

**EDITED:** Sorry... GROUP BY **2**, not 1

Comment: I would use Min because if you have duplicates usually the older one is the best one to keep in our system. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Not sure but wouldn't it be group by 2

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, but I receive the following error: "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: It's not gonna work . Group by 1(2,3) is for mysql. You need to `group by  COALESCE ([Company], [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName])`

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, and props to @a1ex07 for the assist!

Comment: Check answer now. and btw, you can group by 1,2,3 etc in **every** SQL implementation